# Escaping database name in prepared statement with Node

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to use [mysql](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) library to request my database.

I need to use the syntax with query placeholders, so I tried a simple request:

`connection.query('DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ?;', ['mydb']);`

But this leads to :

`'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'\'mydb\'\' at line 1'`

The query is indeed:

`'DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS \'mydb\';'`

So how is this supposed to work actually ?

Comment: try change ['mydb'] to "my_db_name". Like conncection.query('statement', "my_db_name"); And second option: connection.query('DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS (?);', ['mydb']);

Comment: You probably can't use placeholder values for things like database names. These aren't strings.

Comment: @NikolayVetrov Tried both, didn't work.

Comment: @tadman I guess that's true.

Comment: Try another one: connection.query('DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ' + connection.escape(db_name));

Comment: Nope... Still not good

Comment: A database name is an identifier. Escaping functions or query parameters only work for constant values, where you would alternatively use a quoted string literal, quoted date literal, or numeric literal. You can't use them for an identifier like database name, table name, or column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL notation for this is:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `mydb`
```

Since you're escaping it as a string, that's not a database reference it can drop.

Some drivers support alternate placeholders for this very reason:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ??
```

Normally you can't use placeholder values for things like databases, columns or tables as these are treated differently. This is a limitation of the driver.

You just need to be careful on user-supplied values and names with irregular characters in them. These need to be escaped according to [MySQL schema identifier rules](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html).

Comment: Ok, I don't really mind about database name, but for columns and tables, what am I supposed to do exactly?

Comment: It depends on the capabilities of your MySQL driver. Most can't do it as placeholders, so you'll need to do it manually or use a driver function if one is available.

Comment: something like `x => connection.escape(x).replace(/^'(.*)'$/, "$1")` ?

Comment: For example, [this driver](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) supports `??` as a prepared statement placeholder for an identifier. Others use a different notation. The idea here is to conform with MySQL's identifier escaping, as linked in the answer.

Comment: because if I remove the quotes I do get `DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS mydb` which is correct... But I might replace it with backticks

Comment: You don't need quotes on identifiers that are just letters and numbers and don't conflict with MySQL reserved keywords. They don't hurt to add, though.

Comment: `connection.query('DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS \`?\`', [database])` This should work in any case, right ?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry! The doc mention `connection.escapeId` for identifier, and, indeed `??`. I missed this part. I was not sure what identifier meant.

Comment: Added a note about the `??` approach. It's driver-specific though.

Comment: Yes, my bad, I forgot to link the library when I posted the question. It was indeed relative to `mysql` npm package. I didn't heard much about any other one. Thanks a lot for  your help.